# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.web.Admin

Tags: 2013

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.web.Admin
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.codemesh.bootstrap.JarInputStreamBootstrapper.forName(Unknown Source)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_IsLeafType()
   at Com.Tridion.Web.Admin.GetInstance()
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.ComponentPresentationAssembler..ctor(String pageUri)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.ComponentPresentationAssembler..ctor()
   at @@@.@@@.Business.BrokerHelper.GetDynamicComponentPresentation(String componentTCMURI, Int32 publicationID, Int32 templateID, Int32 itemType) in e:\@@@@\Source Code\@@@.Web\@@@.Business\BrokerHelper.cs:line 231

I have checked all the folder location and i found that cd_wai.jar file and cd_wai_conf.xml file is present but still i found this error.Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the community Soubhik, could you please edit your question and add some information about what you are doing so we have a clue as to when you get this error? Just posting a stacktrace doesn't really say much, we can't look over your shoulder and see what you are doing, you will need to explain that to us before we can really help you. Consider us a rubber duck, as explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: yes i am calling a BrokerClass file and that class file i need to initialize the ComponentPresentationAssembler class. During initilization i found this error.

Answer (score 2):

The Admin class is the main class that is used to start and run the Tridion Content Delivery WAI Service. Inability to load this class is *usually* due to the lack of, or a mis-configured, license file.

Check that all the required JARs are in place, that the configuration files refer to the correct location of your license file and that the license file is valid for your server.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your code is running (from a .Net web application from the looks of it) the cd_wai.jar needs to be in the `/bin/lib` subfolder of your web application (not in the `C:\Program files (x86)\Tridion\lib` folder).

It could also be a permission problem; can you verify that authenticated users have at least RX permissions on the jar file (and the parent folder)?